# how does a natural language date parser work?

Tags: javascript, nlp, date-parsing

can someone explain quickly what are the steps that a natural language parser executes to achieve its work?
are the steps the same regardless of language to translate or the language determines the way of translating?

Does exist some multilanguage parser in javascript? I need one in Italian or one I can expand with Italian sentences.

Anyway, my requirements are very simple, the sentences to translate are more or less syntactically similar, so at first, I thought to use a long "if else/switch"  block plus some regular expressions

- one week ago
- three weeks ago
- about 5 months ago
- friday